# symlink on directory permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, symlink

I've created a symlink shown here;

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 apache apache   33 Nov  4 11:55 blog -> /var/www/blog.mysite.com
```

Which resides in the base of this directory

```
/var/www/www.mysite.com/
```

If I attempt to browse to `www.mysite.com/blog` I get a 403 permission denied response. However if I navigate to `www.mysite.com/blog/` (with a trailing slash) Everything works as expected.

I've attempted to insert `.htaccess` rules in both root folders of these to force the trailing slash (`RewriteRule ^[^/]$ /blog/ [L,R=301]`), but it appears that a request without the slash does not hit either `.htaccess` file as intentional errors in either or both of these files, does not affect the 403 response. I'd maybe expect a 500 error when intentionally writing errors here.

All parent folders of these directories have 755 permissions and are owned by root. I tried changing the parent folder owner:group to apache too, but didn't notice and differences.

All other questions I've found on this topic seem to suggest checking the permissions for parent folders, but none of the questions I've found have stated that the smylink actually works with a trailing slash on the folder name.

I've got `Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` set in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. The server runs on CentOS.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006186/trailing-slashes-problem "Trailing slashes problem" ?

Comment: @steve That's unrelated. Under usual circumstances, my server has no issue routing a `/directory` to `/directory/index.php`. This issue is specific to using a symlink. If I manually place an index file in the main domain under `/blog` and remove the smylink, the url with out the trailing slash will work.

Comment: Is `Options FollowSymlinks` set?

Comment: I've got `Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` set in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file